# No corre la primer condición

Tags: java

Cuando corro mi programa, solo se ejecuta la segunda condición del código sea mayo o menor de 3 caracteres.

```
// aqui declaro la variable refNumber
public Book(String bookAuthor, String bookTitle, int bookPages)
{
    author = bookAuthor;
    title = bookTitle;
    pages = bookPages;
    refNumber = ("");
}
```

y solo en este metodo puedo agregar valores a `refNumber`

```
public void setRefNumber(String ref) {
    if (refNumber.length() > 3) {
        refNumber = ref;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Es menor de 3 los caracteres");
    }
}
```

Comment: No hay ninguna variable refNumber, por lo que no entraría

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no tira error de compilacion este codigo? esa variable no existe...

Comment: la variable la tengo declarada en la clase y no me marca ningun error

Comment: Entonces debes colocar bien como está la variable, qué contiene, qué es lo que pasa y lo que esperas que pase

Comment: espero que cuando sea mayor de 3 las caracteres se guarde el dato pero si es menor a 3 me manda el mensaje

Comment: Agregalo a la pregunta al igual donde declaras la variable y cómo se llena

Comment: Cuando cual variable sea menor o mayor a 3 caracteres?

Comment: @gbianchi la variable `refNumber`

Comment: y donde esta definida esa variable? usa el boton [edit] y clarifica la pregunta. si nunca entra en la primer condicion, es porque nunca tiene mas de 3 caracteres. aca no hay ningun error a corregir, solo chequear bien tu codigo

Comment: si muchas gracias ya encontre mi error, fue de lógica, disculpen